# transform rotate pushes div off screen and becomes invisible

Tags: html, css

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/*HEADER*/

#header {
    background: blue;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.btn-1, .btn-2, .btn-3 {
    background-color: white;
    width: 62px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-1 {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    position: relative;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes btn-1-animate {
    from {width: 62px; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
    to { top: 75px; left: -12px; width: 84px;}
}

@keyframes btn-1-reverse {
    from {top: 75px; left: -12px; width: 84px;}
    to {top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 62px;}
}

.btn-2 {
    border-radius: none;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes btn-2-animate {
    from {top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 62px}
    to {top: 58px; left: 65px; width: 117px;}
}

@keyframes btn-2-reverse {
    from {top: 58px; left: 65px; width: 117px;}
    to {top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 62px;}
}

.btn-3 {
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    position: relative;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes btn-3-animate {
    from {top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 62px;}
    to {top: 41px; left: 180px; width: 140px;}
}

@keyframes btn-3-reverse {
    from {top: 41px; left: 180px; width: 140px;}
    to {top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 62px;}
}

.side-menu, .nav-btn {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.nav-btn {
    width: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#header ul {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: -15px 0px lightgreen;
}

.side-menu {
    position: relative;
    left: -370px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    z-index: 1;
}

.fa-times {
    position: fixed;
    left: -380px;
    top: 200px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.fa-times:hover {
    transform: scale(1.3);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#header li a {
    font-family: 'Kumar One Outline';
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    padding: 15px;
    color: grey;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

}

#header li:hover {
    transform: scale(1.15);
}

 #header li {
    margin: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    transition: all 0.35s ease;
 }

 #header li a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #96ea96;
 }

 #header p {
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 }

 /*ABOUT*/

 #about .container {
    background-color: #339966;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: -400px;
 }

 #about h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
 }

 .line {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 0px;
    height: 4px;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 560px;
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
 }

 #about p {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    width: 35%;
    margin-left: 130px;
 }

 .image-slider {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 35%;
    height: 250px;
    margin-right: 160px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: -380px;
    float: right;
 }

 .fa-caret-down {
    color: white;
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-top: 29%;
    position: relative;
 }

 .left {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    left: -40px;
 }

 .right {
    float: right;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    left: 40px;
 }

/*MENU*/

#menu .container {
    background-color: #e6ac00;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-top: -330px;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 3%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.shape-wrap {
 position: relative;
}

.shape-1 {
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid #339966;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: -190px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}

.shape-2 {
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid #26734d;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 10px;
}

.shape-3 {
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid #40bf80;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    left: -195px;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 25px;
}

.shape-4 {
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid #26734d;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: -40px;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 85px;
}

.shape-5 {
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid #339966;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    left: -298px;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 110px;
}

.shape-6 {
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid #339966;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    top: 230px;
    display: inline-block;
    left: -351px;
}

.shape-7 {
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid #26734d;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: -90px;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 265px;
}

.shape-8 {
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid #339966;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    top: 290px;
    display: inline-block;
    left: -405px;
}

.shape-9 {
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid #26734d;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: -140px;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 325px;
}

.shape-10 {
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid #40bf80;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    left: -410px;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 325px;
}

#menu h1 {
    font-size: 7rem;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
    margin-left: 220px;
    position: relative;
    top: -450px;
}

.line-2 {
    background-color: #339966;
    width: 0px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -600px;
    left: 45px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.platter {
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
    color: #339966;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

.platter-info {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
    color: white;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.item {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.price {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
    display: block;
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 40px;
}

.col-1 {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -550px;
}

.plat-4 {
    position: relative;
    left: 120px;
}

.info4tacos {
    position: relative;
    left: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.plat-7 {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
}

.plat-8 {
    position: relative; 
    right: 50px;
}

.plat-9 {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
}

.info4breakfast {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
}

.col-2 {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -3185px;
    margin-right: 200px;
}

.plat-2 {
    position: relative;
    left: 70px;
    top: 15px;
}

.plat-3 {
    position: relative;
    left: 60px;
}

.right-border {
    float: right;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    position: relative;
    top: 2400px;
    right: 18px;
}

/*HOURS*/

#hours .container {
    background-color: #339966;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -470px;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 3%, 5% 0%, 95% 0%, 100% 3%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

#hours h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30px;
}

.day, .hour {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #666;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 220px;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
    border-right: 12px solid #40bf80;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 270px 270px;
    grid-auto-rows: 65px;
    grid-gap: 15px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -272.5px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

.move3 {
    top: 85px;
}

.move10 {
    position: relative;
    top: 265px;
}

.rotate {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>El Metate | Mexican Food</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive|Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif|Kumar+One+Outline|Teko" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Diplomata+SC|Ewert|Sarina|Smokum" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav-btn">
                <div class="btn-1"></div>
                <div class="btn-2"></div>
                <div class="btn-3"></div>
            </div>  
                <div class="side-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                        <li><a href="#header">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#hours">Hours</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <p><span class="auth">Authentic</span><span class="mexi">Mexican</span><span class="food">Food</span></p>
            <img src="img/LogoMakr_Oso9xi.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <h1>About us</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis, quis, adipisci! Unde natus quas officiis, earum commodi! Voluptate in modi alias quisquam maiores sunt fugit reprehenderit odio rem obcaecati libero repellat saepe quidem quibusdam impedit labore error velit, possimus necessitatibus. Optio ullam, officiis, sit ipsa fugiat animi voluptas labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, et.</p>
            <div class="image-slider">
                <i class="fas fa-caret-down left"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-caret-down right"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="menu">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="left-border">
                <div class="shape-wrap">
                    <span class="shape-1"></span>
                    <span class="shape-2"></span>
                    <span class="shape-3"></span>
                    <span class="shape-4"></span>
                    <span class="shape-5"></span>
                    <span class="shape-6"></span>
                    <span class="shape-7"></span>
                    <span class="shape-8"></span>
                    <span class="shape-9"></span>
                    <span class="shape-10"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 385px;">
                    <span class="shape-1"></span>
                    <span class="shape-2"></span>
                    <span class="shape-3"></span>
                    <span class="shape-4"></span>
                    <span class="shape-5"></span>
                    <span class="shape-6"></span>
                    <span class="shape-7"></span>
                    <span class="shape-8"></span>
                    <span class="shape-9"></span>
                    <span class="shape-10"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 770px;">
                    <span class="shape-1"></span>
                    <span class="shape-2"></span>
                    <span class="shape-3"></span>
                    <span class="shape-4"></span>
                    <span class="shape-5"></span>
                    <span class="shape-6"></span>
                    <span class="shape-7"></span>
                    <span class="shape-8"></span>
                    <span class="shape-9"></span>
                    <span class="shape-10"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1155px;">
                    <span class="shape-1"></span>
                    <span class="shape-2"></span>
                    <span class="shape-3"></span>
                    <span class="shape-4"></span>
                    <span class="shape-5"></span>
                    <span class="shape-6"></span>
                    <span class="shape-7"></span>
                    <span class="shape-8"></span>
                    <span class="shape-9"></span>
                    <span class="shape-10"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1540px;">
                    <span class="shape-1"></span>
                    <span class="shape-2"></span>
                    <span class="shape-3"></span>
                    <span class="shape-4"></span>
                    <span class="shape-5"></span>
                    <span class="shape-6"></span>
                    <span class="shape-7"></span>
                    <span class="shape-8"></span>
                    <span class="shape-9"></span>
                    <span class="shape-10"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1925px;">
                    <span class="shape-1"></span>
                    <span class="shape-2"></span>
                    <span class="shape-3"></span>
                    <span class="shape-4"></span>
                    <span class="shape-5"></span>
                    <span class="shape-6"></span>
                    <span class="shape-7"></span>
                    <span class="shape-8"></span>
                    <span class="shape-9"></span>
                    <span class="shape-10"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 2310px;">
                    <span class="shape-1"></span>
                    <span class="shape-2"></span>
                    <span class="shape-3"></span>
                    <span class="shape-4"></span>
                    <span class="shape-5"></span>
                    <span class="shape-6"></span>
                    <span class="shape-7"></span>
                    <span class="shape-8"></span>
                    <span class="shape-9"></span>
                    <span class="shape-10"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="right-border">
                <div class="shape-wrap">
                    <span class="shape-1"></span>
                    <span class="shape-2"></span>
                    <span class="shape-3"></span>
                    <span class="shape-4"></span>
                    <span class="shape-5"></span>
                    <span class="shape-6"></span>
                    <span class="shape-7"></span>
                    <span class="shape-8"></span>
                    <span class="shape-9"></span>
                    <span class="shape-10"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 385px;">
                    <span class="shape-1"></span>
                    <span class="shape-2"></span>
                    <span class="shape-3"></span>
                    <span class="shape-4"></span>
                    <span class="shape-5"></span>
                    <span class="shape-6"></span>
                    <span class="shape-7"></span>
                    <span class="shape-8"></span>
                    <span class="shape-9"></span>
                    <span class="shape-10"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 770px;">
                    <span class="shape-1"></span>
                    <span class="shape-2"></span>
                    <span class="shape-3"></span>
                    <span class="shape-4"></span>
                    <span class="shape-5"></span>
                    <span class="shape-6"></span>
                    <span class="shape-7"></span>
                    <span class="shape-8"></span>
                    <span class="shape-9"></span>
                    <span class="shape-10"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1155px;">
                    <span class="shape-1"></span>
                    <span class="shape-2"></span>
                    <span class="shape-3"></span>
                    <span class="shape-4"></span>
                    <span class="shape-5"></span>
                    <span class="shape-6"></span>
                    <span class="shape-7"></span>
                    <span class="shape-8"></span>
                    <span class="shape-9"></span>
                    <span class="shape-10"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1540px;">
                    <span class="shape-1"></span>
                    <span class="shape-2"></span>
                    <span class="shape-3"></span>
                    <span class="shape-4"></span>
                    <span class="shape-5"></span>
                    <span class="shape-6"></span>
                    <span class="shape-7"></span>
                    <span class="shape-8"></span>
                    <span class="shape-9"></span>
                    <span class="shape-10"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1925px;">
                    <span class="shape-1"></span>
                    <span class="shape-2"></span>
                    <span class="shape-3"></span>
                    <span class="shape-4"></span>
                    <span class="shape-5"></span>
                    <span class="shape-6"></span>
                    <span class="shape-7"></span>
                    <span class="shape-8"></span>
                    <span class="shape-9"></span>
                    <span class="shape-10"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 2310px;">
                    <span class="shape-1"></span>
                    <span class="shape-2"></span>
                    <span class="shape-3"></span>
                    <span class="shape-4"></span>
                    <span class="shape-5"></span>
                    <span class="shape-6"></span>
                    <span class="shape-7"></span>
                    <span class="shape-8"></span>
                    <span class="shape-9"></span>
                    <span class="shape-10"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h1>Menu</h1>
            <div class="line-2"></div>

            <div class="vexel-images"></div>

            <div class="col-1">
                <h3 class="platter">Combination Platters</h3>
                <p class="platter-info">Rice & Beans Included</p>

                <p class="item item-1">Tostada & Taco</p><span class="price p1"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
                <p class="item item-2">2 Beef Tacos</p><span class="price p2"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
                <p class="item item-3">2 Enchiladas</p><span class="price p3"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
                <p class="item item-4">Tostada & Enchilada</p><span class="price p4"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
                <p class="item item-5">Taco & Enchilada</p><span class="price p5"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
                <p class="item item-6">Burrito & Enchilada</p><span class="price p6"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
                <p class="item item-7">2 Beef Burritos</p><span class="price p7"><span class="s1">$</span>7.45</span>
                <p class="item item-8">2 Carne Asada Tacos</p><span class="price p8"><span class="s1">$</span>8.09</span>
                <p class="item item-9">Chorizo</p><span class="price p9"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
                <p class="item item-10">Carne Asada</p><span class="price p10"><span class="s1">$</span>8.19</span>
                <p class="item item-11">Machaca</p><span class="price p11"><span class="s1">$</span>6.75</span>
                <p class="item item-12">Carnitas</p><span class="price p12"><span class="s1">$</span>7.19</span>
                <p class="item item-13">2 Fish Tacos</p><span class="price p13"><span class="s1">$</span>6.75</span>
                <p class="item item-14">Chiles Rellenos</p><span class="price p14"><span class="s1">$</span>6.95</span>
                <p class="item item-15">Red Combo</p><span class="price p15"><span class="s1">$</span>7.95</span>
                <p class="item item-16">Green Combo</p><span class="price p16"><span class="s1">$</span>7.05</span>
                <p class="item item-17">3 Rolled Tacos w/Guacamole</p><span class="price p17"><span class="s1">$</span>6.75</span>
                <p class="item item-18">Chimichanga, Rice & Beans</p><span class="price p18"><span class="s1">$</span>7.05</span>
                <p class="item item-19">Carne Asada Burrito</p><span class="price p19"><span class="s1">$</span>7.19</span>
                <p class="item item-20">2 Tamales, Rice & Beans</p><span class="price p20"><span class="s1">$</span>7.05</span>

                <h3 class="platter plat-4">Tacos</h3>
                <p class="platter-info info4tacos">Folded</p>

                <p class="item item-21">1 Chicken Taco</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.09</span>
                <p class="item item-22">1 Beef</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.09</span>
                <p class="item item-23">1 Carne Asada</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.61</span>
                <p class="item item-21">1 Fish</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
                <p class="item item-22">1 Carnitas</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
                <p class="item item-23">1 Adobada</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
                <p class="item item-23">1 Cabeza</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>

                <p class="platter-info info4tacos">Rolled</p>

                <p class="item item-21">3 Plain with Cheese</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.39</span>
                <p class="item item-22">3 Cheese and Guacamole</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.89</span>
                <p class="item item-23">3 Chicken w/Cheese and Guacamole</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.89</span>
                <p class="item item-21">3 Tacos w/Cheese and Guacamole</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>3.99</span>
                <p class="item item-22">12 Tacos w/Cheese and Guacamole</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>8.99</span>

                <h3 class="platter plat-7">Tortas</h3>

                <p class="item item-21">Carne Asada</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.09</span>
                <p class="item item-22">Machaca</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.09</span>
                <p class="item item-23">Ham</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.61</span>
                <p class="item item-21">Chorizo</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
                <p class="item item-22">Chicken</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
                <p class="item item-23">Carnitas</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
                <p class="item item-23">Fish</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>

                <h3 class="platter plat-8">Breakfast Served Everyday</h3>
                <p class="platter-info info4breakfast">6am to 11am</p>

                <h3 class="platter plat-9">Breakfast Plates</h3>

                <p class="item item-21">Huevos Racheros</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>6.29</span>
                <p class="item item-22">Steaks Racheros</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>6.95</span>
                <p class="item item-22">Scrambled Eggs w/Ham</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>5.95</span>
                <p class="item item-22">Scrambled Eggs w/Suasage</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>5.95</span>
                <p class="item item-22">Chorizo Omelette</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>6.95</span>
                <p class="item item-22">Carne Asada Omelette</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>7.95</span><p class="item item-22">Scrambled Eggs w/Ham</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>5.95</span>
                <p class="item item-22">Eggs and Bacon</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>5.95</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-2">
                <h3 class="platter plat-2">Enchiladas</h3>

                <p class="item item-21">2 Cheese</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
                <p class="item item-22">2 Beef</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
                <p class="item item-23">2 Chicken</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>

                <h3 class="platter plat-10">Breakfast Burritos</h3>

                <p class="item item-21">Suasage & Egg</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>4.09</span>
                <p class="item item-22">Ham & Eggs</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.09</span>
                <p class="item item-22">Bacon & Eggs</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.09</span>
                <p class="item item-22">Steak & Chorizon</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.75</span>
                <p class="item item-22">Picodegallo eggs & cheese</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>3.95</span>
                <p class="item item-22">Chorizo & Eggs</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.85</span>
                <p class="item item-22">Chorizo & Eggs</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.09</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="hours">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 250px; left: 70px;">
                    <span class="shape-1"></span>
                    <span class="shape-2"></span>
                    <span class="shape-3 move3"></span>
                    <span class="shape-4"></span>
                    <span class="shape-5"></span>
                    <span class="shape-6"></span>
                    <span class="shape-7"></span>
                    <span class="shape-8"></span>
                    <span class="shape-9"></span>
                    <span class="shape-10 move10"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="shape-wrap rotate" style="top: 230px; left: 200px;">
                    <span class="shape-1"></span>
                    <span class="shape-2"></span>
                    <span class="shape-3 move3"></span>
                    <span class="shape-4"></span>
                    <span class="shape-5"></span>
                    <span class="shape-6"></span>
                    <span class="shape-7"></span>
                    <span class="shape-8"></span>
                    <span class="shape-9"></span>
                    <span class="shape-10 move10"></span>
                </div>
            <h1>Hours</h1>
            <div class="hours-line"></div>
            <div class="hours-line2"></div>

            <div class="grid">
                <div class="day">Sunday</div>
                <div class="hour">8am - 8pm</div>
                <div class="day">Monday</div>
                <div class="hour">6am - 10am</div>
                <div class="day">Tuesday</div>
                <div class="hour">6am - 10am</div>
                <div class="day">Wednesday</div>
                <div class="hour">6am - 10am</div>
                <div class="day">Thursday</div>
                <div class="hour">6am - 10am</div>
                <div class="day">Friday</div>
                <div class="hour">6am - 10am</div>
                <div class="day">Saturday</div>
                <div class="hour">6am - 10am</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hey Guys I'm currently working on the hours section to this website. Specifically I'm working on the design for the left and right border. The left side consists of two sets of shapes. You can see the first one there, and what i want is a duplicate of that shape pattern but rotated 180 degrees. This however pushes it way off to the right of the screen and renders it invisible. I saw something on this site talking about how if the div is 2D it will treated as if it were 3D, except i think that was rotateY. anyway any help would be appreciated.

p.s i hade to take out a lot of code so i could post this so sorry the menu section looks messed up

Comment: Can you fiddle it?

Comment: yah give me a sec

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e251pksa/

Comment: it looks fine to me. Not sure exactly what you are looking at. Maybe the browser you are looking it at.

Comment: its because i have the rotate property on it. I took it off so if you scroll down to the hours section now you'll see two sets of shapes instead of one. if you want to put that property back on to watch it dissapear its the very last css selector

Comment: nvm I guess I didnt do anything. But if you go to that last css selector and take off that rotate property you'll see it

Answer (score 1):

That happens because the div is to large. You can either set `position: absolute` or limit the div size  `width: 500px`

Comment: the parent div to all the shapes?

Comment: i don't understand how that would change it like that?

Comment: I just explained it. Because it's too large and not correctly positioned. You can read about position property and width property